# Dropdown for AutoCompleteTextView has items but they are not visible

Tags: android, android-layout, autocompletetextview

I'm using the AutoCompleteTextView component to filter member data. I've set it up in my layout file as follows

```
     <AutoCompleteTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/autocomplete_swap_pool"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/nfl_my_listings_and_my_bids_spinner_height"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/icon_on"
            android:dropDownSelector="@color/black"
            android:dropDownVerticalOffset="5dp"
            android:dropDownWidth="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textAutoComplete|textAutoCorrect"
            android:popupBackground="@color/white"
            android:ems="10"
            android:text="" />
```

I've then initialised it in my code like this

```
        autoTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) EngineGlobals.iRootActivity.findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_swap_pool);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(EngineGlobals.iApplicationContext, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, Cards);
        autoTextView.setThreshold(1);
        autoTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

When I enter text the dropdown box appears but the items are not visible, they are there because if I click on the dropdown box items appear. It looks as if they are white font on a white background.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: user final static int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 }; to pass SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = 
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
                    android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, null,
                    from, to);
        mStateNameView.setAdapter(adapter);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to apply `textColor` to your `hint`. For that you need custom row `layout` for your `AutoCompleteTextView`.

*hint_item.xml*

```
<TextView
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />
```

*YourActivity.java*

```
AutoCompleteTextView autoTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete_swap_pool);
    ArrayAdapter<String> autoadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.hint_item, new String[]{"One", "Two", "Three"});
    autoTextView.setAdapter(autoadapter);
```

*Output*

[image]